# Using Moq setting up all methods of a mock equally

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq

Let's assume I have the interface

```
public interface A {
  int Foo1();

  int Foo2();

  int Foo3();
}
```

and a testing method with a mock (using **[Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/)**) like

```
Mock<A> mock = new Mock<A>();
```

Now there are basically two testing scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

I want to test what my system-under-test does if the interface implementation throws a specific exception on any method. So I want to setup all methods to throw the same exception like

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo1()).Throws(new Exception());
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo2()).Throws(new Exception());
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo3()).Throws(new Exception());
```

**Scenario 2**

I want to test what my system-under-test does if the methods return any number. So I could think of setup the mock like

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo1()).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo2()).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo3()).Returns(1);
```

**Reason:**
I have many different unit tests for the system-under-test. Some of them are tests for business logic where it makes a difference e.g. *what* values are returned. But some are just small tests for general behavior, e.g. if the system-under-test throws an exception if one of the used components throws one. Or the opposite, that the system-under-test throws no exception if all components behave as expected. And for these small tests I'm using code like above right now.

**Question:**
Is there a smarter way to initialize all (matching) methods of a Mock the same way? Something like

```
mock.SetupAll().Throws(new Exception());
```

or

```
mock.SetupAll<int>().Returns(1);
```

(which means: setup those methods which have a return type of `int`)?

Comment: I don't think these are supported. Note that if you use Mock.Strict on a mock i.e var mock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);, if the setups haven't been configured for those mocks in your tests, your test would fail.

Comment: I'm sure that there's nothing native to Moq that could do this, but you could write an extension method that does what you want using reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved with `SetReturnsDefault`, like:

```
mock.SetReturnsDefault(1);
```

See `SetReturnsDefault` in the source for more info: [Moq on github](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/src/Moq/Mock.cs)

Comment: And in the case where he wants exceptions, he could use `new Mock<A>(MockBehavior.Strict)` and (again) not perform any `.Setup(...)`. Then every call will throw an exception. Not `new Exception()` though, but a specific exception saying member has not been setup.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Sorry for the delay, I could not test this in the past weeks. But it works. @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks also for your suggestion, in my scenario it is very helpful because I just want to test what happens if *any* exception occurs.